# In PHP what is optimal filepath reference method on webserver

Tags: php

When including other files in your PHP scripts, what is faster for webserver to process:

```
include 'http://www.mydomain.com/bin/scripts/thescript.php';
```

OR

```
include '/home/user/public_html/bin/scripts/thescript.php';
```

OR

```
include '../../scripts/thescript.php';
```

OR is there really no practical difference in the real world?

This is not an academic question. If all three methods are equally satisfactory in real time, please tell me. That's all I need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute, i.e. strating with "/" is always better. That way if you move your app you don't have to manually update the path names. I use a combo of 2 functions to define the absolute path as a constant.

```
function tsl($path) {
    if (substr($path, strlen($path) - 1) != '/'){
        $path .= '/';
    }
}
function get_root_path() {
  $pos = strrpos(dirname(__FILE__),DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'inc');
  $adm = substr(dirname(__FILE__), 0, $pos);
  $pos2 = strrpos($adm,DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
  return tsl(substr(__FILE__, 0, $pos2));
}
define('ROOTPATH', get_root_path());
```

I am using inc/ in my example, but you can change this. This will allow you to just use the constant ROOTPATH rather than trying to figure out the path evertime.

Another way is like this...

```
<?php
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
define('ROOT_URL', substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, - (strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) - strlen(ROOT_DIR))));
?>
```

Just include the file with these defines in your template page.

Comment: Ok, and how do you include this function for other files to use the ROOTPATH constant?

Comment: Edited my post. You just have to make sure the file containing these defines is included in an page that uses them. I usually call all my pages from index.php so I just need to include it once.

Comment: Ok, so you never deal with AJAX request on a PHP file that again, includes other PHP files? Just curious, that's all :)

Comment: @dbf Funny you should mention ajax. I am running into a problem with absolute file referencing in an ajax routine. It's premature to say that absolute referencing is the problem just yet (in process of debugging) but `funny you should mention`. Do you have experience with ajax/abs ref?

Comment: @gibberish well at least you followed :P I don't want to takeover the OP but yea, there are several methods, and I believe there is a very blog from someone, when you google it, what reliable options are (shared hosting, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is not recommended at all, since includes using HTTP protocol is a potential security hole and isn't allowed on most serious hosters - it is slower as well, since it'll load through the network.

Method 2 and 3 are somewhat equivalent I guess (gut feeling, haven't done any benchmarks).

Method 3 allows you to move your PHP application around without having to correct the absolute path.

Comment: Your observation vis Method 3 (relative path) is correct IF you move the entire app around. I'm asking this question b/c I'm relocating the include files within the app structure and have a ton of paths to correct because the relative paths have changed. So, I guess "it's all relative" to what one ends up moving around. X^/